# Uploading file with fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm new to Solr and I've just finished the tutorial. At this point I want to see if I can add files (for example PDF files), but with associated fields.

The problem is that the example from the tutorial uses the bin/post (simple post tool) command, but it seems to be able to only either post XML files with fields, or other files (e.g. PDF files) without fields.

But I want both: I want to be able to query based on the contents of the PDF file *and* at the same time limit the search based on field values. How would I approach this problem? Is this possible in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the help of `Tika-config.xml`.
It all depends on where are the files located and what metadata you want to index.

You can configure the `tika-config.xml` and run the indexing.

The `tika-config.xml` will look like below.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="file" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" dataSource="null"
            baseDir="${solr.install.dir}/example/exampledocs" fileName=".*pdf"
            rootEntity="false">

      <field column="file" name="id"/>

      <entity name="pdf" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
              url="${file.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">

        <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
        <!-- in the original PDF, the Author meta-field name is upper-cased,
          but in Solr schema it is lower-cased
         -->

        <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
        <field column="dc:format" name="format" meta="true"/>

        <field column="text" name="text"/>

      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

You also need to modify the solrConfig.xml.
Add the below entry and run the data-import handler.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">tika-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

If you are using managed schema then you may not need to add any fields in the schema file.

Below are the link that might give you an idea on the same.

[Solr wiki DIH Page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/DataImportHandler)

[Solr File Indexing Example](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/apache-solr-indexing-all-files-in-a-folder-recursively/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not clear to me though how I would (for example) add a searchable field user="12345" to the indexed document (note that 12345 is to be supplied by me at time of indexing, and does not occur in the document).

Comment: In this case you can read the content of the document and the metadata of the document using the tika. You can use the solrj api and create a solr document and add the data that is been read. Along with that data you can add other fields and the values for those fields as part of the solr document. Once solr document (which is an entity) ready then you can send it to solr sever and commit it.